# How to loop through all files in a folder in DolphinDB

Tags: filenames, dolphindb

I would like to import all csv files in a loop to a DolphinDB database. Is there a function to extract all file names in a folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
exec filename from files(yourdir)
```